# How to fix this sql to show only the last row instead of all that fulfill the query conditional?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use the following sql, to show the active users that browsed a website the last 5 minutes. The rows then are presented with the browsed page. However, if a user (hash) browses many pages in 5 minutes, all are displayed.

What I want to show is only the last page per user. How can I do this?
The limit 1 does not work because I want to show the last page for all active users. Not only 1 user.

```
SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       behaviour.page 
FROM   active 
       inner join behaviour 
               ON active.hash = behaviour.hash 
WHERE  active.last_active >= Now() - interval 10 second 
       AND behaviour.timestamp >= Now() - interval 5 minute 
ORDER  BY behaviour.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER  BY behaviour.timestamp LIMIT 1` shows only the first record (the last of your actual query)

Comment: @fantaghirocco limit 1 would be ok if there was only one user. But the problem is that it has to show the last page of each user.

Comment: so is `MAX(behaviour.timestamp)` ... `GROUP BY user_column`? User's reference is missin in the SQL

Comment: "active user" is in the question, but the query says "hash" and "page".  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @fantaghirocco can you point me exactly where to add it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for what you are doing:

```
SELECT b.hash, b.page 
FROM active a join
     behaviour b
     ON a.hash = b.hash join
     (select b2.hash, max(timestamp) as maxts
      from behavior b2
      where timestamp >= Now() - interval 5 minute 
      group by b2.hash
     ) bh
     ON bh.hash = b.hash and bh.maxts = b.timestamp
WHERE  a.last_active >= Now() - interval 10 second 
ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC ;
```

It gets the maximum timestamp in a subquery and joins that back in.

Comment: Unknown column 'b2.hash' in 'field list'